# How to add performance testing to mocha tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, performance-testing, load-testing

I'd like to do performance testing for the following unit test.

```js
describe("simple test", async() => {
     it("first test", async() => {
        assert.equal(myProgram(), 1);
     })
})
```

But I'm not sure where to start.

How can I add performance testing tools to my mocha unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

Two options are [**mocha-performance**](https://github.com/holidayextras/mocha-performance) & [**benchtest**](https://github.com/anywhichway/benchtest)

## mocha-performance

*Runtime performance analysis off the back of a mocha test suite*

1. Install with

   ```bash
   npm install mocha-performance
   ```
2. Add **`--allow-natives-syntax`** and **`--reporter mocha-performance`** to your existing mocha script runner like this

   ```bash
   node --allow-natives-syntax ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --reporter mocha-performance ./test/**/*.js
   ```

## benchtest

*Integrated performance testing for Mocha based unit testing*

1. Install with

   ```bash
   npm install benchtest --save-dev
   ```
2. Add two global Mocha event hooks

   ```js
   const benchtest = require("benchtest");
   beforeEach(benchtest.test);
   after(benchtest.report);
   ```
3. Add a `#` to the end of each unit test name you wish to benchmark or use the option `all:true`